# Applescript to execute script in new terminal window and maintain a reference to that window

Tags: applescript

How do I use applescript to execute a script in a new terminal window and then close the window?

After the line:

```
set x to do script ""
```

Is there a way to get a reference to the window of tab x? A reliable way - not something like "frontmost window".

Answer (score 0):

`do script` returns the tab the script was run in:

```
tell application "Terminal" to do script ""
result -- tab 1 of window id 6166 of application "Terminal"
```

I don't know any way to close the tab or get its window though. `window 1` should refer to the window opened by `do script`:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "sleep 2; logout"
    tell window 1
        repeat until processes of selected tab is {}
            delay 0.01
        end repeat
        close
    end tell
end tell
```

If others were looking for how to run `do script` again in the same window:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "uptime"
    do script "uptime" in result -- or window 1
end tell
```

Comment: I want to find a way that won't generate an error, but using window 1 could result in errors, so I was hoping for a way around that.